# Boost atomic 128 bit atomic type x86_64

Tags: c++, boost, atomic

How do I use the boost::atomic<> template so that I get real 128 bit (16 byte) CAS, load and store?
Problem is that even tough boost 1.55.0 atomic library says it has now 128 bit support I only get fake spinlock emulated implementation. E.g. following code will fail:

```
struct ui128_t { uint64_t low, high; };
boost::atomic<ui128_t> atom;
assert(atom.is_lock_free());
```

I checked the BOOST_ATOMIC_INT128_LOCK_FREE macro which is set to false for some reason I don't know. I'm using MSVC 2012 x64 compiler.

Comment: I don't think you can make a 128bit operation atomic, you can however put a lock on it until its completed, using an atomic type that the platform actually supports.

Comment: For lack of better ideas, you could try with a builtin type like _m128 (the type for SSE instructions).

Comment: x86_64 has the `lock cmpxchg16b [ptr]` instruction which is atomic. MSVC supports or at least should support this via _InterlockedCompareExchange128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not actually released yet: it appears to be in 'trunk' only.

You can use a command line

```
grep -R BOOST_ATOMIC_INT128_LOCK_FREE boost/
```

to find out which compilers support it